# Changing the sign (+ or -) of a number based on non-matching columns

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk

I'm having a bit of an issue with an awk script which should probably be pretty simple.

I have files which looks like this, which have thousands of rows, with columns 2 and 3 consisting of G,C,T and A; and 4,5,6 numeric (only column 4 has negative values):

```
ID A1 A2  BETA  SE     P
1  A  T   0.01  0.001  0.2
2  G  G   0.02  0.003  0.4
3  C  T  -0.02  0.005  0.1
4  T  T  -0.01  0.006  0.2
```

What I'm aiming to do is to change the sign of the number (positive to negative and vice versa) in column 4 if columns 2 and 3 do not match. So the result should look like this:

```
ID A1 A2  BETA  SE     P
1  A  T  -0.01  0.001  0.2
2  G  G   0.02  0.003  0.4
3  C  T   0.02  0.005  0.1
4  T  T  -0.01  0.006  0.2
```

My go to attempt at doing this is with awk:

```
awk '{if($2 != $3 print $0}'
```

Which I realise is not much of a start to a simple problem, but I can't figure out how to change both `+` to `-` and vice versa in one go.

A solution would be great, with steps on how it works even better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `awk`:

```
awk 'NR!=1&&$2!=$3{$4=$4*-1};1' file
```

- If the condition `$2!=$3` is true and it's not the first line (`NR!=1`), multiply the value of `$4` with `-1`.

---

If you want fixed columns again use `column`:

```
awk 'NR!=1&&$2!=$3{$4=$4*-1};1' file | column -t
```

- The `-t` flag of `column` determines the number of column by itself and creates a table.

Output:

```
ID  A1  A2  BETA   SE     P
1   A   T   -0.01  0.001  0.2
2   G   G   0.02   0.003  0.4
3   C   T   0.02   0.005  0.1
4   T   T   -0.01  0.006  0.2
```

Comment: Ah, thanks - so simple. But shouldn't it be: awk '$2=!$3{$4=$4*-1}1' file to get the desired output?

Comment: @Asfound Yes sure, sorry misread in the question, I changed it in the answer

Comment: I also added the condition to ignore the first line as header line.